# Objective C - NSCalendar to a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nscalendar

I need to convert a NSCalendar to a NSString to show date and time splitted in two differents UITextView
I can't found a way to do this.
All examples convert NSDate to NSString, but I need to do that with a NSCalendar!

Thanks for your help and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Your problem is you don't know what is a calendar.

Comment: A `NSCalendar` is just an object that encapsulate information about systems of reckoning time. You may use a calendar to convert a date to calendar components (year, month, day, etc) or get the components between two dates. There no date or time associated with a calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Java where [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) objects represent instances of time, `NSCalendar` is a class that lets you perform operations on `NSDate` objects, without representing a particular point in time at all.

You can use an instance of `NSCalendar` to split an `NSDate` into date components (day, month, hour, etc.) according to a specific calendar, to add a number of time units to an `NSDate`, or compose a bunch of date-time components into an `NSDate`. You could then convert the `NSDate` to a string using `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks, I come from Java and sometimes I make this mistakes. So, I have to use always NSDate? Even if I have to same Date + Time

Comment: @MarkComix Yes, `NSDate` is capable of keeping both a date and a time.

Comment: @MarkComix Honestly, I think that `java.util.Calendar` is one of the most confusing names one could pick for a class of such fundamental importance.